# Queue with "unlimited" buffer in Go

Tags: asynchronous, queue, go

This is small piece of bigger puzzle, but usable by its own.
It an attempt to have a nonblocking queue with "unlimited" (besides memory size) buffer length.

Got unit-tests 100% statement coverage, it looks that it's ok, but I'm very new to Go and concurrency so I might miss something.

```
import "sync"

// Message and MessageQueuer are interfaces, defined in other file

type msgQueue struct {
    input, output     chan Message
    buffer            []Message
    head, tail, count int
    immediateClose    bool
    done              sync.WaitGroup
}

func NewQueue() MessageQueuer {
    mq := &msgQueue{
        input:  make(chan Message),
        output: make(chan Message),
        buffer: make([]Message, 16),
    }

    mq.done.Add(1)

    go mq.magicBuffer()

    return mq
}

func (mq *msgQueue) In() chan<- Message {
    return mq.input
}

func (mq *msgQueue) Out() <-chan Message {
    return mq.output
}

func (mq *msgQueue) Len() int {
    return mq.count
}

func (mq *msgQueue) Close() {
    close(mq.input)
}

func (mq *msgQueue) CloseAndWait() {
    close(mq.input)
    mq.done.Wait()
}

func (mq *msgQueue) ClearAndClose() {
    mq.immediateClose = true
    mq.count = 0
    close(mq.input)
}

func (mq *msgQueue) enqueue(msg Message) {
    if mq.head == mq.tail && mq.count > 0 {
        buffer := make([]Message, len(mq.buffer)*2)

        copy(buffer, mq.buffer[mq.head:])
        copy(buffer[len(mq.buffer)-mq.head:], mq.buffer[:mq.head])

        mq.head = 0
        mq.tail = len(mq.buffer)

        mq.buffer = buffer
    }

    mq.buffer[mq.tail] = msg
    mq.tail = (mq.tail + 1) % len(mq.buffer)
    mq.count++
}

func (mq *msgQueue) dequeue() Message {
    msg := mq.buffer[mq.head]

    mq.head = (mq.head + 1) % len(mq.buffer)
    mq.count--

    return msg
}

func (mq *msgQueue) shutdown() {
    defer mq.done.Done()

    if mq.immediateClose {
        mq.buffer = nil
    }

    for mq.count > 0 {
        mq.output <- mq.dequeue()
    }

    close(mq.output)
}

func (mq *msgQueue) magicBuffer() {
    for {
        if mq.count == 0 {
            msg, open := <-mq.input

            if open && !mq.immediateClose {
                mq.enqueue(msg)
            } else {
                mq.shutdown()

                return
            }
        } else {
            select {
            case msg, open := <-mq.input:
                if open && !mq.immediateClose {
                    mq.enqueue(msg)
                } else {
                    mq.shutdown()

                    return
                }

            case mq.output <- mq.buffer[mq.head]:
                // dequeue
                mq.head = (mq.head + 1) % len(mq.buffer)
                mq.count--
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder why did you choose do it with channels. You can do much better with mutexes.